# `arc` fails to parse appium.txt file, failing out at the first line

Tags: android, ruby, appium

I'm trying to set up a local test rig for Appium before trying some cloud services. I've got the Appium.app running locally and have put together a very small test script in Ruby (using xpath). I'm trying to utilize `arc` (the Appium Ruby Console) to do some further scripting but am having trouble getting it launched. I've got everything installed (`appium_lib`, `appium_console`) and best I can tell it should be working. However, when I run the `arc` command at the terminal, I get the following error:

```
Failed to match sequence (ALL_SPACE (TABLE / TABLE_ARRAY / KEY_VALUE / COMMENT_LINE){0, } ALL_SPACE) at line 1 char 1.
`- Don't know what to do with "﻿[caps]\n  " at line 1 char 1.
```

Here are the contents of my `appium.txt` as of now.

```
[caps]
appium-version: '1.0',
platformName: 'Android',
platformVersion: '4.4',
deviceName: 'Nexus_5_API_22_Lollipop',
app: '/Users/justinr/Desktop/Development/TMSampleAndroid-master/app-debug.apk',
appPackage => 'com.marketlytics.calabashtest',
appActivity => 'com.marketlytics.calabashtest.MainActivity'
```

Thanks a ton in advance for any insight - please let me know if there are other useful files to see.

Answer (score 0):

Running the `arc setup android` got this working for me (it stumps an `appium.txt` in the current directory). Still not sure what the problem with my original file was, though - I can't see any key differences.